# 2048 Merge Function

Tags: python, merge, coding-style, pylint, pep8

## 2048 Merge Function

#### From: Principles of Computing Part 1 Course on Coursera

I got `-2` pts on my OWLTEST which uses Pylint for style guide. The error states:

> Too many branches (17/12)
>       function "merge", line 7

what does that mean?

I worked really hard on making this program work. I wrote this from scratch. I would also like to know if there are some techniques to make this cleaner and/or some best practice improvements? I know there are probably ways to write this in a better way because right now my code looks really messy.

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Thu Sep  3 17:55:56 2015
    2048_merge_attempt1.py
    @author: Rafeh
    """
    def merge(nums):
        '''
        Takes a list as input 
        returns merged pairs with
        non zero values shifted to the left.
        [2, 0, 2, 4] should return [4, 4, 0, 0]
        [0, 0, 2, 2] should return [4, 0, 0, 0]
        [2, 2, 0, 0] should return [4, 0, 0, 0]
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2] should return [4, 4, 2, 0, 0]
        [8, 16, 16, 8] should return [8, 32, 8, 0]
        '''
        slide = []  # Append non-zeroes first
        for num in nums:
            if num != 0:
                slide.append(num)
        for num in nums:
            if num == 0:
                slide.append(num)
        pairs = []
        for idx, num in enumerate(slide):
            if idx == len(slide)-1:
                pairs.append(num)
                if len(pairs) != len(nums):
                    pairs.append(0)
                break
            if num == slide[idx+1]:
                if num != 0:
                    pairs.append(num*2)
                    slide[idx+1] -= slide[idx+1]
                    # slide[idx+1], slide[idx+2] = slide[idx+2], slide[idx+1]
                else:
                    pairs.append(num)
            else:
                    pairs.append(num)  # Even if they don't match you must append
        slide = []  # Append non-zeroes first
        for num in pairs:
            if num != 0:
                slide.append(num)
        for num in nums:
            if num == 0:
                slide.append(num)
        for _ in range(len(nums) - len(slide)):
            if len(nums) != len(slide):
                slide.append(0)
        return slide
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Oh, thanks. Did not even know that existed. I posted it there.

Answer (score 0):

A 'branch' is a place in the control flow of your program where the control may 'branch' in more than one way, i.e. a different set of statements is executed. A good example is an 'if' statement which always has two branches. E.g.

```
a()
if e:
  b()
c()
```

If you ignore the possibility of exceptions or `sys.exit()` calls or the like, there are two branches: `a(); b(); c()` in case `e` is true. Or `a(); c();` in case `e` is false.

In your case, there are a lot of `if` statements which could be replaced. For instance, instead of

```
for num in nums:
    if num != 0:
        slide.append(num)
```

you can write

```
slide += [num in nums if num != 0]
```

Now, this loop is repeated all over the place. So I'd suggest to do it just once, at the top, and have

```
nonZeroNums = [num in nums if num != 0]
```

and then use that.